# Browser only respects first domain in certificate

Tags: google-chrome, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am generating a self-signed certificate which I have added to my keychain and I can see that it is used by Firefox and Chrome.
But when I visit `https://world.localhost`, the bowser says the certificate is invalid because it is issued for `localhost`. All the domains below are integrated into the certificate. When I change their  order, I can see that the browser only respects the top most entry (`DNS.1`) when compared to the requested domain, but all the domains are in the certificate when I view it (through the browser).

What is wrong in this case?

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = dev.cert.key
distinguished_name  = subject
#req_extensions      = req_ext
req_extensions      = v3_req
x509_extensions     = x509_ext
string_mask         = utf8only

[ x509_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid,issuer

basicConstraints  = CA:FALSE
keyUsage          = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName    = @alternate_names
[ v3_req ]

subjectKeyIdentifier = hash

basicConstraints    = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName      = @alternate_names

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = localhost
DNS.2       = *.localhost
DNS.3       = *.test.localhost
DNS.4       = *.www.localhost
DNS.5       = *.api.localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working as expected is, the browser classifies the most right part as the Top-Level domain.

Wildcard certificates like `*.com` are not valid, and so is `*.localhost`.

When I put another *label* into, the whole thing works.

`*.domain.localhost` matches `www.domain.localhost` and **is valid**.

`*.localhost` matches `www.localhost` but is **not valid**.